# Prove that for all elements n that are member on set N, 0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3 +....+ n(n+1) = n(n+1)(n+2)/3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The problem is :Prove that for all elements n that are member on set N, 0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3 +....+ n(n+1) = n(n+1)(n+2)/3

I have established a base case for n=0, 0*1 = 0(0+1)(0+2)/3 = 0
I have also established a pattern for n=4, n=5, and n=6

0*1+1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5 = 40

4(5)(6)/3 = 40

0*1+1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5+5*6 = 70

5(6)(7)/3 = 70

0*1+1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5+5*6+6*7 = 112

6(7)(8)/3 = 112

After establishing a base case and a pattern, I am having trouble finding the right way to explain this proof.

Comment: A pattern? What pattern do you see in $40, 70, 112$?

Comment: The pattern is on the left of the equation.

Comment: The pattern is not in the integers 40,70,112. It is that the formula works for f(4), f(5), and f(6).

Comment: Well that's not really a pattern. That's just showing it works for three arbitrary values.

Comment: OK, how do I go from showing that the formula works for 3 arbitrary values to proving that the formula works for all values of n?

Comment: Through induction. (See my answer)

Comment: Please do not write in this ugly way. Don't say "for all elements n that are member on set N". Simply say "for all n in N" or even "for all natural numbers n".

Comment: Thank you, I was having trouble bridging the gap.

Comment: The sum can be re-written as $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^nk(k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\big(k^2+k\big)= \sum_{k=0}^nk^2+\sum_{k=0}^nk.~$ Now see [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to use induction (note that finding that it holds true for three arbitrary cases doesn't lead us anywhere)

Your base case is fine. From then, you must first assume that it holds true for  $k$ -- this is the inductive step. You must then show that, if it holds for $k$, then it holds for $k+1$. Thus, letting $k = 0$ (the base case), we would then know that $k+1 = 1$ works. Since we know $k = 1$ works, we then know that $k +1 = 2$ works as well. See where this is going? This is essentially the thought behind using induction. So let's do it.

Inductive step: Assume $0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3 + \dots + k(k+1) = k(k+1)(k+2)/3$

We want to show that $0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3 + \dots + k(k+1) + (k+1)(k+2) = (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)/3$. Substitute the inductive step to get $k(k+1)(k+2)/3 + (k+1)(k+2) = (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)/3$. The rest is just algebra and I'll leave that to you.